# What happens if NSURLCache is full?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlcache

I'm using default NSURLCache to cache images in my iPhone app.
What will happen if the cache is full and i'll try to cache another image?

Will it not cache the image? or it will be replaced with the oldest image cached?

Thanks alot

Comment: It's behavior is not described at documentation, however I'd expect from Apple to have something better than FIFO, e.g. the cached responses weight might be increased based on the cache hits counter. And the behavior is most likely different for memory/disk layers.

Comment: If the system increases the allocated cache memory by itself, than what is the purpose of declaring the cache size on creation?
I actually believe it's kind of FIFO but i'm not sure and my testing seems inaccurate. i'm not sure what to expect if my cache is 50mb and it get's filled

Comment: Simply said no kind of cache is supposed to provide any kind of data integrity, otherwise that is a database, not a cache, and you need to handle it differently.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum cache can be influenced with the initialization
   initWithMemoryCapacity:... diskCapacity:... diskPath:..]
The new file will always be downloaded. (except when it's bigger than the maximum memory capacity, then it will just be downloaded and not saved in the cache)
If the maximum cache size is reached other file(s) will be removed.
It is not specified what files will be removed.
It's not difficult to create your own NSUrlCache and handle it yourself.
if you want to see a sample how to do that, then have a look at https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache