# AlamoFire 5.0 force permanent caching

Tags: ios, swift, caching, alamofire

I am using AlamoFire 5.0 and want to force permanent cache storage of data fetched from urls (.obj files, .png images etc.). Is there some way to ignore/intercept the HTTP headers sent by the server and just force permanent caching?

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
            var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
        }

let request = AF.download("http://someurl.com", to: destination)

request
    .response(completionHandler: { (response) in
         //handle response data
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider Disk caching your response.
This answer might be of help:
[Disk Cache Images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38621600/7767758)